# Trying to add an open source car library to my android project, I am having issues adding it correctly

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I create a libraries folder under my root folder in my Android Studio project.
I then copy the car-library folder into libraries, i include `:libraries:car-lib` to the settings.gradle file.
I even compile project(`:libraries:car-lib`) in the build.gradle.

I get the following Error:

> Error:(16, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory
>   'libs'] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Open
>   File

One more issue i think is that the car-lib does not have a gradle file at all?

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:car-lib'
```

build.gradle under the app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.s26150.testingapi"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


        compile project(':libraries:car-lib')
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':libraries')
}
```

How am i supposed to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you perhaps post your gradle settings file and your app build file?

Comment: You are using dependencies inside another dependencies. Not so sure you can do it.